# C#: Load referenced assembly based on framework version?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to load a referenced assembly only if the .NET Framework version is lesser than a specific number ?

I'm using a selfmade LINQ library on .NET 2.0, but if the framework is 3.5+, it should use the M$ LINQ library, and ignore the selfmade one.

**Edit:**
Here's my library: 
http://linq4you.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why use your own LINQ implementation when you could use the existing [linqbridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/)?

Comment: Because unlike LINQBridge, my assembly supports lambdas and expression trees, as demonstrated and required by Linq.Dynamic, and I plan on integrating LINQ 2 SQL & XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by modifying your project file.

Open your csproj file in a text-editor, and find the line in the project file that describes the dependency that you want to conditionally load, and make sure that it looks like this, for instance:

```
<Reference Include="LinqBridge" Condition="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)=='v2.0'">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\DevSupport\Lib\LinqBridge\LinqBridge.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```